# install zebra sdk android

Tags: java, android, windows, zebra-printers

I'm having really trouble installing the latest Zebra SDK version for Windows (mpsdk-installer-2-8-Windows.exe).

Installer was downloaded from the Zebra's website (LINK-OS MULTIPLATFORM SDK).

The installer (LaunchAnywher) throws "Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM" when it gets 100%:

I tried 2 workarounds I found in google:

- Include the Java folder path into the Path environment variable.
- Run installer from cmd: mpsdk-installer-2-8-Windows.exe LAX_VM
  C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe

None of them works (my OS is Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bits).

Just for check I got an older version of the Zebra SDK (ZebraSDK1.0.121.exe) and installation did ok.

After that I created JAVA_HOME variable environment but I still get the same error.

Then I created the environment variable for my user ...and didn't work either.

Even I tried the installer and the same procedure in other devices (win7 and win10 32bits) getting the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved the problem.

It was as simple as getting the sdk contained in the zip file downloaded from:

"[Zebra Technologies - Connect and Print Over TCP/IP and Bluetooth – Zebra Android Link-OS™ SDK – Java – Android Studio](https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/SAMPLE_CODE/0/SA370/en_US/AndroidSDK_Java_ConnectAndPrint_AndroidStudio.zip)"

Once gotten the sdk I added the dependency to my project, followed the steps of the example and everything worked like a charm!

Best regards.

P.S. The official installer (LaunchAnywere) still throws the same error (tried in 5 computers).

Answer (score 0):

The link in the other answer is no longer functional. I was unable to find a zip version of the SDK after hours of searching so I dug into the errors that were being thrown.

The error was an illegal reflective access. I wasn't sure what that meant but apparently it was something that changed in Java 9 so the install Anywhere installer requires JDK 8.

The solution, for me, was to install JDK 8, downloaded from the Oracle archives, which precedes the changes to the way reflective accesses are handled. I then added that JDK version to my path and ran the installer again. To my great relief, it worked. I hope this helps someone else running into this problem.